# Suddenly .py files can't import modules but still works with CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I have a weird issue.

**Main issue:**
My .py files that used to work fine like 3 hours ago now can't import any external modules. I can still run them from Spyder (similar to a PyCharm editor) and from CMD with `python run.py`. However when clicked on I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ModuleName`. However the module is found when running through everything else, the module is there in the Anaconda libs; the folder doesn't have any permisson restrictions, and it's not just one file it's any .py file that imports an external module.

At first I thought this may be a pip issue as I had just update to pip 18, but even when retracting to pip 10.0.1 the issue remains.

[EDIT]: I've tried making a PyInstaller .exe and that still works as intended, however the app still doesn't work with cx_freeze even though it used to a fez hours ago.

**Backstory:**
I was playing around with PyInstaller and Cx_Freeze to turn my app into an executable.

I have my working .py file that I edit and test inside of the Anaconda's Spyder app.

And so I'm testing the executables, and they work fine, just like my python code. The Pyinstaller standalone and the cx_freeze app work as intended.

So I change a few things in the main .py file (nothing crazy just removed a print('')), reuse cx_freeze and then at some point I start working on a setup wizard for my cx_freezed app.

It's all good except that when running the app, the cmd prompt just closes.
I think 'huh weird', I test the .py file in Spyder it works fine, so I screenshot what's written on the cmd : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ModuleName`, so I think it's an issue with the Wizard installer, so I try the original .exe file, same error. So I try the .py file and to my desmise, same error. I double check the modules, reinstall them succesfully, error persists.

And so I try to run a backup I know for sure worked and in which I haven't edited anything, and now same error.

This is really anoying as I want to make a .exe of the app, managed to and now nothing works anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things you can try.
Add this code to get a print out of the system path.

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

That should tell you all the paths where modules can be loaded from. If your file is not in one of the paths it won't be loaded.

For a bit more info you can run python with the `-v` flag and it will verbosely let you know what is going on as python starts as well as when you attempt to load modules.  You may be able to glean information about what is going wrong that way.

Comment: I think I found my issue, when running your code through Spyder and cmd I get the Anaconda3 libs (which should and was default, where all my modules are installed) however, when running directly through .py file, I get a Python 3.7 local directory I didn't even knew I had installed and existed. meaning for some reason  in the last 3 hours the default for the .py files has suddenly changed from the Anaconda directory to python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the wrong version when you converted from a .py to .exe. Generally the CMD uses whatever's in the ENV vars, so just make sure all version numbers are the same.